# Grep pattern matching omitting parts in output

Tags: regex, grep

Is it possible using just one `grep` and `regexp` combination to achieve the following. Say I have a file like so:

```
$ cat f.txt
line 1 foo
line 2 boo
no match
line 3 blank
line X no match
```

I want to match all the lines that start with the word `line` and followed by a number but only display the what come after that, so the part that is matched by `(.*)`.

```
$ grep -E '^line [0-9]+(.*)' f.txt 
line 1 foo
line 2 boo
line 3 blank
```

Can you say match but don't display this part `^line [0-9]+` like doing the inverse of  `grep -o '^line [0-9]+'`

So my expected output would look like this

```
$ grep -E ***__magic__*** f.txt 
foo
boo
blank
```

Comment: In other words, you need to show only `foo`, `boo` and `blank`? If so, couldn't you just add the expected output to the question? It'll make it much more clean.

Comment: Couldn't you have just edited the question if you thought it was unclear. The example isn't important, I just want to know if its possible to omit certain parts of the match from the output using `regexp`

Comment: Sigh. With regexes, examples (of input and expected output) are ALWAYS important - I've yet to see the question that contradicts this rule. Anyway, it's not possible to use the capturing groups with grep, I suppose.

Comment: Its possible with -P option in grep. check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/22928443/950979

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example file:

```
$ cat cat_1.txt
line 1 foo
line 2 boo
no match
line 3 blank
line X no match
```

This is easy with Perl:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /^line \d+ (.*)/' cat_1.txt
```

Or with [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-0):

```
sed -En 's/^line [0-9]+ (.*)/\1/p' cat_1.txt
```

Either case, prints:

```
foo
boo
blank
```

Comment: I like the sed solution, I have accepted this answer but it says I  need 15 reputation to upvote :/

Comment: @user100101011: Thanks! Someone else seems to have down-voted for no explained reason. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use sed

```
~$ cat 1.txt
line 1 foo
line 2 boo
no match
line 3 blank
line X no match


$ grep -E '^line [0-9]' 1.txt | sed 's/^line [0-9] //'
foo
boo
blank
```

**UPDATED**
...or without using sed

```
$ grep -E '^line [0-9]' 1.txt | grep -oE '[a-z]*$'
foo
boo
blank
```

Comment: actually, yes. I put 'cat' just for visibility