# How to display part of matched pattern in grep?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I wanted to extract 12 from a text like "abc_12_1". I am trying like this

```
echo "abc_12_1" | grep -Eo '[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9]+_1'
abc_12_1
```

But I am not able to select the digit after first _ in string, the  output of above command is whole string. I am looking for some alternative in grep which I have in following Perl pattern matching.

```
perl -e '"abc_55_1" =~ m/[a-zA-Z]+_([0-9]+)_1/ ; print $1'
55
```

Is it possible with grep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `perl`:

```
$ echo "abc_12_1" | perl -lne 'print /_(\d+)_/'
12
```

or `grep`:

```
$ echo "abc_12_1" | grep -oP '(?<=_)\d+(?=_)'
12
```

Comment: echo "__12_1" | grep -oP '(?<=_).*?(?=_)' even this gives out put 12. in this case I don't want to match, can you tell how to mandate a text in the beginning in your expression

Comment: @Renjith Try `echo "_12_1" | grep -oP '(?<=[[:alpha:]]_)(\d+)(?=_)'`

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `awk`

```
echo "abc_12_1" | awk -F_ '{print $2}'
12
```

Or `grep`

```
echo "abc_12_1" | grep -o "[0-9][0-9]"
12
```

Using `grep` with extended regex

```
grep -oE "[0-9]{2}"     # Get only hits with two digits
grep -oE "[0-9]{2,}"    # Get hits with two or more digits
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `cut`:

```
cut -d_ -f2 <<< "abc_12_1"
```

Using `grep`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=_).*?(?=_)' <<< "abc_12_1"
```

Both would yield `12`.